# Access denied when writing to file in RStudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio-server

In RStudio Server I want to write to the directory `/var/www/r_diagnostics`:

```
f <- "/var/www/r_diagnostics/test.txt"
writeLines("test", con = f)
```

The name of my user is `randomuser`.

```
> system("whoami")
randomuser
```

The directory permissions for `r_diagnostics` are set as:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 randomuser randomuser   4096  6. Jan 18:15 r_diagnostics
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: Do you have execute permission for each directory in the path?

Comment: If you have access to the folder with winscp, then you can change its permissions by right clicking on the folder

Comment: @MatthewLundberg No, I do not. Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: It is absolutely necessary.

Comment: okay, great thank, x-rights did the job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a file, you have to find the directory.  This requires execute permission for each element in the path.  Execute permission allows you to find a directory's contents.

Plus, you also need write permission to the final leaf directory in order to modify a file (you had that already).